# Using C++ filestreams (fstream), how can you determine the size of a file?

Tags: c++, filesize, fstream, istream

I'm sure I've just missed this in the manual, but how do you determine the size of a file (in bytes) using C++'s `istream` class from the `fstream` header?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282549/c-getting-incorrect-file-size/2289423#2289423

Comment: @NarendraN - that doesn't use fstream, as this question explicitly asks for

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can seek until the end, then compute the difference:

```
std::streampos fileSize( const char* filePath ){

    std::streampos fsize = 0;
    std::ifstream file( filePath, std::ios::binary );

    fsize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
    fsize = file.tellg() - fsize;
    file.close();

    return fsize;
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, is the first call to `tellg` not guaranteed to return 0?

Comment: @Steve Honestly, I am not sure. I couldn't figure it out from the standards :(

Comment: I  had to remove the subtraction aspect - but just reading `file.tellg()` after the `seekg()` gives the same byte size as is reported by the shell (running on CentOS 4 with g++ 3.4.6)

Comment: I wonder why in the 21st century we still have to count the size of the stream manually? Why don't the commitee just make a function for that which everybody could use? Isn't it just that simple? Are there any hidden caveats?

Comment: @rightaway717: They could. But why? C++ is not a language where "everything is done for you". It provides the building blocks then it's up to you to do whatever you want with them. It would be a complete waste of time to create a function to serve just this one specific use case. Besides, a simple "getter" could easily mislead people into not realising that a file seek is involved, which may have ramifications for them in all sorts of cases. It's better to have people do this explicitly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: while I do understand what you mean, I still do not agree. Many other functions are also that primitive to serve their specific usecase, like get the length of a string. This is a pretty common operation to get the size of things to make a function for it. I believe you do it as well in your code - provide a function to know the size of your own classes, if size has a meaning for them.There are also plenty of function that do a (potentially) long operation under the hood, like vector resizing for example. that doesn't mean that we have to make people do it explicitly.

Comment: @rightaway717: Getting the length of a string is a completely different operation, as I've pointed out already. Vector resizing is clearly a mutating operation so not a good example.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And hundreds thousands developers substracting beginning from end is not a waste of time... If the pointer was actual byte position, with 0 guaranteed, the case would be different. Also, a common stat() call can return the value - the data is already there - without performing any seeks. Meanwhile, we have the file.tellg(ios::begin) value made accessible, which IS completely useless; a piece of under-the-hood data that by itself is useless, and its only purpose is to allow the developer to combine it with another under-the-hood value to extract something useful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, on most systems getting the file size by subtracting offests returned by tell's operations is a slower operation than just directly getting the size of the file which is stored somewhere in the inode or similar structure in the filesystem itself. So, whilst the fallback algorithm could be the one that uses seek's and tell's, an optimized implementation could work around that and provide a faster approach. How's that a bad thing?

Comment: @FabioA.: Because the abstraction that is C++ knows about streams of data (some seekable), not "files" or "inodes". That is beyond its purview. You're quite right that you can make more performant programs by using your particular system's API, and that's great! Feel free to go ahead and do that. But I see no reason for C++ to hardcode any of that implementation detail for the general case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I oughta remind you of [std::streamsize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize). Clearly, c++ streams do have a concept of "size", and since they do also have a concept of "end of stream" (see seekg), in my opinion it does make sense to have a size() method that defaults to the implementation depicted above.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What new information should I gather from a comment that I already read and didn't change since?

Comment: @FabioA.: You could understand it properly this time ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You might try to explain yourself better, if you think you weren't able to properly convey what you meant.

Comment: @FabioA.: I conveyed it okay :) I like how the recipient always forgets that the responsibility for communication is on _both_ parties. Doesn't matter anyway so never mind, and have a nice evening. :)

Comment: Nevermind indeed, it seems the forgetful one is you, here.

Comment: If the file you have open is a pipe or a socket or a signalfd, what should a "get_file_size" function return?

Comment: @rightaway717 in C++ 17, they finally added it!. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size)

Answer (score 109):

You can open the file using the `ios::ate` flag (and `ios::binary` flag), so the `tellg()` function will directly give you directly the file size:

```
ifstream file( "example.txt", ios::binary | ios::ate);
return file.tellg();
```

Comment: @Dominik Honnef: in VS 2013 Update5 64 bit this approach, with _ios:ate_ flag and without _seekg(0, ios:end)_ might not work for large files. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057750/how-to-get-the-filesize-for-large-files-in-c for more information.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good approach. [tellg does not report the size of the file, nor the offset from the beginning in bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22986486/1835769).

Comment: @displayName [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) kind of disagrees with that statement: it indeed uses `tellg()` to detect filesize.

Comment: the answer below works in all situations and not this one, since it returns 0 in lot of cases when the pointer is at the beginning of the file

Comment: This is a totally incorrect answer and gives 0 in many cases.

Answer (score 47):

Don't use `tellg` to determine the exact size of the file. The length determined by `tellg` will be larger than the number of characters can be read from the file.

From stackoverflow question [tellg() function give wrong size of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984956/tellg-function-give-wrong-size-of-file) `tellg` does not report the size of the file, nor the offset from the beginning in bytes. It reports a token value which can later be used to seek to the same place, and nothing more. (It's not even guaranteed that you can convert the type to an integral type.). For Windows (and most non-Unix systems), in text mode, there is no direct and immediate mapping between what tellg returns and the number of bytes you must read to get to that position.

If it is important to know exactly how many bytes you can read, the only way of reliably doing so is by reading. You should be able to do this with something like:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

ifstream file;
file.open(name,std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
file.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() );
std::streamsize length = file.gcount();
file.clear();   //  Since ignore will have set eof.
file.seekg( 0, std::ios_base::beg );
```

Comment: My... I guess I'll continue to use `stat()`.

Answer (score 11):

Like this:

```
long begin, end;
ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
begin = myfile.tellg();
myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
end = myfile.tellg();
myfile.close();
cout << "size: " << (end-begin) << " bytes." << endl;
```

Comment: You may want to use the more appropriate `std::streampos` instead of `long` as the latter may not support as large a range as the former - and `streampos` *is* more than just an integer.

Comment: Isn't your `begin` just 0?

Answer (score 11):

Since C++17, we have [`std::filesystem::file_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size). This doesn't strictly speaking use `istream` or `fstream` but is by far the most concise and correct way to read a file's size in standard C++.

```
#include <filesystem>
...
auto size = std::filesystem::file_size("example.txt");
```

Comment: After running benchmarks, I realize it's also running much faster than the istream variant, on Windows at least.

Comment: Does it return the actual file size or the file size determined by the OS? The OS will report a size bigger than the actual size, since most OSs use blocks for space

Comment: @Raildex filesize returns the size determined as if by reading the st_size member of the structure obtained by POSIX. Copied from  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size

Answer (score -8):

I'm a novice, but this is my self taught way of doing it:

```
ifstream input_file("example.txt", ios::in | ios::binary)

streambuf* buf_ptr =  input_file.rdbuf(); //pointer to the stream buffer

input.get(); //extract one char from the stream, to activate the buffer
input.unget(); //put the character back to undo the get()

size_t file_size = buf_ptr->in_avail();
//a value of 0 will be returned if the stream was not activated, per line 3.
```

Comment: all this does is determine if there is a first character. How does that help?