# fastest way to count lines of a file in c++ if length of lines are fixed?

Tags: c++, file, lines

title says it all.

I have a file where all lines have the same length.

what's the fastest way to count the number of lines in c++?

Comment: Divide the length of the file by one more than the length of a single line.

Comment: How to get the size is a common question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409504/using-c-filestreams-fstream-how-can-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file

Comment: @Blender And by two more on windows?

Comment: @michel bollard - my boyfriend does ask that a lot :-)

Comment: @user3125367: text files can have bare-`CR`, bare-`LF` or `CRLF` line breaks.  Many/most Windows apps recognize bare-`LF` and `CRLF`, at least.  I imagine many apps on other platforms do as well.  It is not uncommon to move text files between platforms.  So you should open the file and analyze the first couple of lines to discover the actual line length and line break being used, then adjust the file size calculation accordingly.