# C++: Getting size of all files inside current directory

Tags: c++, filesize

I'm new to C++ programming, and I'm trying to practice file reading and writing. I'm trying to get the sizes of all the files of the current directory. Thing is, after getting the names of the files in the current directory, I place them inside of a text file. So now I'm stuck, and don't know where to go from here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

                // FILE FUNCTION

void fileStuff(){

}

                // MAIN FUNCTION

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
// ERROR CHECKING
if(argc != 3){ // IF USER DOESN'T TYPE ./nameOfFile, AND THE OTHER REQUIRED ARGUMENTS.

    cout << "Incorrect. Try Again" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

ifstream file;
string fileContents;

system("find . -type f > temp.txt");

file.open("temp.txt");

if (!file){

    cout << "Unable to open file: temp.txt" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}
while(file){

    getline(file, fileContents);
    cout << fileContents << endl;
}

file.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using C++ filestreams (fstream), how can you determine the size of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409504/using-c-filestreams-fstream-how-can-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file)

Comment: You put them in a text file and...? What do you want to do next?

Comment: After I've put those files into a text file, I want to be able to output the size of those files as well.

Comment: `fileContents` is the name of one of the files. Open it and count the number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

[C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) (and earlier versions, notably [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11)) does not know about [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) and [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)) (yet). For C++17, see its [file system library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs). Otherwise, your code is operating system specific, but Boost library has some [file system support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

I am assuming you are running on Linux or some POSIX system.

Your program just uses an external command ([find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)); if you want to read from such a command, you might use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) with `pclose`, then you won't need a temporary file. BTW, you could use `find . -type f -ls`.

However, you don't need to use an external command, and it is safer (and faster) to avoid that.

<sup>Pedantically, a file name could contain a newline character, and with your approach you'll need to special case that. A file name could also contain a tab character (or other control characters) and in that case `find . -type f` behave specifically, and you would also need to special case.  In practice, it is extremely poor taste  and very unlikely to have a newline or tab character in a file name and you might forget these weird cases.</sup>

You could use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html). You could recursively use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) & loop on [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) (and later `closedir`).

Once you have a file path, you would **use [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to get that file's metadata, including its size** (field `st_size`). BTW the `/bin/ls` and `/usr/bin/find` programs use that.

The [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) function returns a `struct dirent` pointer ending with `d_name`; you probably want to skip the two entries for `.` and `..` (so use [strcmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to compare with `"."` and `".."`, or do the compare the hard way). Then you'll build a complete file path using string catenation. You might use (in genuine C++) [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) or you could use [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) for that. If you `readdir` the current directory `.` you could call [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) directly on `d_name` field.

BTW `exit(-1)` is incorrect (and certainly poor taste). See [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html). A much more readable alternative is `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`

Comment: [Boost example](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Directory-size-via-boost-filesystem-problem-td2563938.html)