# File.exe has Triggered a Breakpoint because of Fseek

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fstream

I'm trying to determine how big a file i'm reading is in bytes so I used Fseek to jump to the end and it triggered the error: file.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
Heses the code:
FileUtils.cpp:
    #include "FileUtils.h"

```
namespace impact {

    std::string read_file(const char* filepath)
    {
        FILE* file = fopen(filepath, "rt");
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        unsigned long length = ftell(file);
        char* data = new char[length + 1];
        memset(data, 0, length + 1);
        fseek(file, 0 ,SEEK_SET);
        fread(data, 1, length, file);
        fclose(file);

        std::string result(data);
        delete[] data;
        return result;
    }

}
```

FileUtils.h:

```
    #pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


namespace impact {
    std::string read_file(const char* filepath);
}
```

If more info is required just ask me for it I would be more than happy to provide more!

Comment: `FILE* file = fopen(filepath, "rt");` -- You did not check if the file opened successfully.

Comment: For more details about how to determine the size of a file using fstream,I suggest you could refer to the links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409504/using-c-filestreams-fstream-how-can-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840148/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in the C way, C++ has much better (in my opinion) ways of handling files.

Your error looks like it *may* be caused because the file didn't open correctly (you need to check if `file != nullptr`).

To do this in C++17 you should use the standard library `filesystem` 
(Note: You can also do this with C++11 `experimental/filesystem` using `std::experimental::filesystem` namespace)

Example:

```cpp
std::string read_file(const std::filesystem::path& filepath) {
    auto f_size = std::filesystem::file_size(filepath);
    ...
}
```

Additionally to read a file in C++ you do not need to know the size of the file. You can use streams:

```cpp
std::string read_file(const std::filesystem::path& filepath) {
   std::ifstream file(filepath); // Open the file

   // Throw if failed to open the file
   if (!file) throw std::runtime_error("File failed to open");

   std::stringstream data; // Create the buffer
   data << file.rdbuf(); // Read into the buffer the internal buffer of the file
   return data.str(); // Convert the stringstream to string and return it
}
```

As you can see, the C++ way of doing it is much shorter and much easier to debug (helpful exceptions with descriptions are thrown when something goes wrong)

Comment: It says that file_size is not a member of filesystem. Is there a fix?

Comment: file_size was added in C++17 so make sure you are using a C++17 compiler and the <filesystem> (not experimental/filesystem) header. Else use C++11's experiment/filesystem and std::experimental::filesystem

Comment: I tried to use filesystem instead of experimental/filesystem but when i did it said filesystem is not a namespace

Comment: `std::filesystem` im guessing your missing the std part?

Comment: Ive included that too also im using visual studio 2019

Comment: So you are saying writing ``` #include <filesystem>\n int main() {std::filesystem::file_size("."); return 0;}``` give you an error?

Comment: not exactly but pretty much I have included filesystem and ive used std::filesystem::file_size and filesystem throws an error

Comment: Try the code above, youve probably spelled `filesystem` wrong or something (also you are passing something to file_size right?)

Comment: With VS2019 it's not in C++17 mode by default.  You need to right-click your project, click "properties" and under "General" make sure that "C++ Language Standard" is set to "ISO C++17 Standard (std:c++17)" to use the `<filesystem>` header correctly.  Damned annoying, but the default is C++14 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019

Comment: That fixed it but im running in to an other problem on the line where it creates the buffer it throws the error incomplete type not allowed on data

Comment: Sounds like your missing the iostream header

Comment: Im still having the problem

Comment: You need `filesystem` `string` `iostream` `fstream` and `sstream` for this to compile

Comment: It is still giving me that error it stops when i put a zero in the square brackets but that throws a different error

Comment: What square brackets??? And are you sure it's not throwing the runtime error which i added to that to purposefull check the file is opened? There are no square brackets i assure you

Comment: Sorry somehow there where square brackets now there is an unresolved external error on the line where I'm testing the code:                                                                                       std::string contents = read_file("Include.h");
std::cout << contents << std::endl;

Comment: I fixed the problem but now its saying Unhandled exception at 0x77233DB2