# filestream to vector, filesize wrong

Tags: c++11, vector, filestream, filesize

I found many articles to this question, but none explained this in enough detail and I am still unexperienced with streams:
I want to stream a file to a vector and this vector is already defined and contains some data.

This snippet seemed to work (it doesnt):

```
std::ifstream fileInputStream(path.wc_str(), std::ios::binary);
//byteVector contains some data and is of type: std::vector<unsigned char>*
byteVector->insert(byteVector->end(), 
  std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(fileInputStream), 
  std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>());
```

In this article I found a method to get the length of my file:
[Using C++ filestreams (fstream), how can you determine the size of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409504/using-c-filestreams-fstream-how-can-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file)

```
std::ifstream fileInputStream;
fileInputStream.open(path.wc_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
fileInputStream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
std::streamsize fileLength = fileInputStream.gcount();
fileInputStream.clear();   //  Since ignore will have set eof.
fileInputStream.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
```

If I compare the vector->size from the first snippet and the fileLength from the second snippet, my vector is about 2KB short.

I want to avoid copying the data from one buffer to another, so if I need more buffers to read all data I'd prefer std::move or something similar. Someone has an idea whats wrong in my first snippet or how to accomplish this another way?

Should I read the file into another vector buffer and move that vector to the end of my first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>` is a *formatted input* iterator that skips whitespace, that is why your vector is short.

Use [`std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) instead, it reads data verbatim.

Note that the meaning of the template argument is quite different between these two iterators. In the latter case it is the type of symbols decoded by [`std::char_traits<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) (e.g. you may want to decode a utf-8 encoded file as sequence of `wchar_t`). `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` does identity decoding. C++ streams have been using `char` type for representing binary data (see [`std::ostream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write), for example).

Comment: That actually worked! Can you give me a little more information, why <char> is used instead of <unsigned char>? The vector I insert the data in should require <unsigned char>

Comment: @Natulux Added a note for you.