# Portable way to get file size in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, portability, filesize, platform-independent

I need to determin the byte size of a file.

The coding language is C++ and the code should work with Linux, windows and any other operating system. This implies using standard C or C++ functions/classes.

This trivial need has apparently no trivial solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282549/c-getting-incorrect-file-size/2289423#2289423

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using std's stream you can use:

```
std::ifstream ifile(....);
ifile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);//seek to end
//now get current position as length of file
ifile.tellg();
```

If you deal with write only file (std::ofstream), then methods are some another:

```
ofile.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
ofile.tellp();
```

Comment: Open the file in binary or you might get the wrong result. Text ifstreams could do `\r\n` to `\n` translation for instance.

Comment: The problem is that tellg() returns a value of type streampos. It is usually an int, but it can also be another type. Though I'll keep it as an answer.

Comment: My answer actually reflects that fact because my first iteration was off the top of my head until someone pointed out the mistake and marked me down for it.

Comment: Isn't an ifstream inefficient if you just want to get the file size? stat() will do it without having to open & seek.

Comment: -1: Opening file is bad idea. Moreover, you cannot check size of, for example, `/etc/shadow` this way.

Comment: To improve a bit on this method, if you seek file size just after opening, you can also do : 
std::ifstream ifile(..., std::ios_base::ate);
It will put the cursor directly at the end of the file, and you gain 1 line of code :)

Comment: File could be failed to open. -1

Comment: @user707779 Don't downvote just for that, it is a simple example, when you're copying this code just add error checking.

Answer (score 6):

You can use stat system call:

```
#ifdef WIN32 
_stat64()
#else
stat64()
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `stat` family of functions is part of POSIX, so they work on UNIX and UNIX-like systems as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the file size this is certainly overkill but in general I would go with [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) for platform-independent file operations.
Amongst other attribute functions it contains

```
template <class Path> uintmax_t file_size(const Path& p);
```

You can find the reference [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Attribute-functions). Although Boost Libraries may seem huge I found it to often implement things very efficiently. You could also only extract the function you need but this might proof difficult as Boost is rather complex.

Comment: Why boost when there are already numerous ways to easily do this without boost?

Comment: Chances are that if you work with files you might need more file functionality: boost is a good choice for that - standard body agrees and will add boost based library to STL. If you really only need file size - by all means use @Dewfy answer

Answer (score 1):

```
std::intmax_t file_size(std::string_view const& fn)
{
  std::filebuf fb;

  return fb.open(fn.data(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::in) ?
    std::intmax_t(fb.pubseekoff({}, std::ios::end, std::ios::in)) :
    std::intmax_t(-1);
}
```

We sacrifice 1 bit for the error indicator and standard disclaimers apply when running on 32-bit systems. Use `std::filesystem::file_size()`, if possible, as `std::filebuf` may dynamically allocate buffers for file io. This would make all the `iostream`-based methods wasteful and slow. Files were/are meant to be streamed, though much more so in the past than today, which relegates file sizes to secondary importance.

Working [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9ZvhmtkIfR9PDdS6).

Answer (score 0):

Simples:

```
std::ifstream ifs; 
ifs.open("mybigfile.txt", std::ios::bin); 
ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::end); 
std::fpos pos = ifs.tellg();
```

Comment: On 32-bit systems, size_t is 32 bits.  So this fails with files of 4GB or larger.

Comment: I wrote this off the cuff with no reference.  Looking at my code there are some problems which I have corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Portability requires you to use the least common denominators, which would be C. (not c++)
The method that I use is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long filesize(const char *filename)
{
FILE *f = fopen(filename,"rb");  /* open the file in read only */

long size = 0;
  if (fseek(f,0,SEEK_END)==0) /* seek was successful */
      size = ftell(f);
  fclose(f);
  return size;
}
```

Comment: Too bad if you have a file >2GB in size on platforms with 32 bit long int

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there are 64 bit versions of those functions. but that aside, this requires you to be able to open the file and is also a lot slower.

Answer (score 0):

The prize for absolute inefficiency would go to:

```
auto file_size(std::string_view const& fn)
{
  std::ifstream ifs(fn.data(), std::ios::binary);

  return std::distance(std::istream_iterator<char>(ifs), {});
}
```

[Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tLL5rie4VsylPIOW).

Answer (score -1):

Often we want to get things done in the most portable manner, but in certain situations, especially like this, I would strongly recommend using system API's for best performance.